# Java strange ceil conversion

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I don't know why, but I'm getting two different result if I'm changing the parameter from a decimal to a fraction.

These methods would return the exact value. I'm trying to round up a number if it's a decimal, for example:

> 0.0 -> 0
>
> 0.1 -> 1
>
> 0.4 -> 1
>
> 0.5 -> 1
>
> 0.6 -> 1
>
> 1.0 -> 1
>
> 1.1 -> 2

```
// accepts Double
private void myRound(Double d){
   int res = (int)Math.ceil(d);
   return (res <= 0 ? 1 : res);
}

// acepts int
private void myRound(int i){
   int res = (int)Math.ceil(i);
   return (res <= 0 ? 1 : res);
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(myRound(14 / 10));
```

> OUTPUT: 1

```
System.out.println(myRound(1.4);
```

> OUTPUT: 2

Comment: You example output doesn't match your example code (not least because you're never calling `myRound`).

Comment: You could replace the version for ints with `Math.max(i, 1)` as the ceiling for an int is the int itself.

Comment: I suppose your code is actually something like is: System.out.println( myRound(1.4) ); isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that firstly the conversion goes to Integer, where (14/10) is 1, and then it ceils it to 1. 1.4 is a double, so it makes it ceil as a double number.

Comment: To be more specific: 14/10 is *exactly* 1. Not 1.0, but 1. Converting either the 14 or the 10 to a float or a double (by adding a `d` or `f` after them, or `.0` for a double) makes the result of the division 1.4 as one might expect (or at least close enough).

Comment: Not just could, it **is** the cause.

Comment: @MichaelMyers, yeah, my bad. It is 1.

Comment: This is correct.  Because both 14 and 10 are int, the results of division will be an int.  I bet if you did 14.0 and 10.0 it would work.

Answer (score 3):

`14/10`, as you've written it, is `1`, because both `14` and `10` will be `int` and so the result is an `int`.

What you've listed as your output doesn't match your code (not least because the code you've shown never calls `myRound`), but I suspect that would be the explanation for whatever you're actually seeing.